# Python import failing due to duplicate path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below scripts,

```
backend/scripts/factories.py
backend/monitor/models.py
scripts/scripts/industry/industry.py
```

In industry.py I have,

```
from monitor.models import abc
from scripts.factories import xyz
```

It is failing with error,

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts.factories'
```

At the same time monitor.models is working. Is it happening because of same path 'scripts' exists twice? If yes how can I solve this? Please advise.

Comment: Either use relative imports (`from ....backend.scripts.factories import xyz`, in this case, assuming that `backend` and `scripts` share a parent directory), or maybe try specifying the exact file (possible relative to `industry.py`'s location) using [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html)

Comment: @HpLam yes it is already there.

Comment: Or you can try import full path `from backend.scripts.factories import xyz`

Comment: My guess is you don’t have the right `sys.path`.  Cd to top level dir and run `python -m scripts.scripts.industry.industry`.  This will put top level dir in path.

Comment: it could see the scripts/scripts as a duplicate path, so maybe change the path name

Comment: @HpLam I tried this but it didn’t work.